# How to change the paths for JS files inside runtime in a build project in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, build, runtime

I am working with angular 8, I have finished my project and I have used **lazy loading**, after having my project ready I have done an ng build --prod (therefore I generated several javascript files).

[image: Dist]
We use Django as a server, and because of our way of working we separate the JS and CSS files in a folder and the index.html in the root, what is the problem?
What the files to be called within the runtime file have an undefined path, I see that it has a src function that returns the location of the file, but I don't know how to modify this function.

Inside to runtime.js we have this

[image]

After performing a console.log in the variable "**u.p**" I can see **EMPTY**, 
How can I modify a U.P. variable/function? I want to place u.p. = "js /" (I have manually replaced u.p with what I need and it works, but I want it to be automatic) I understand that it must be an Angular.json configuration or an extra command when doing the ng build --prod

Comment: One does not simply modify the dist folder! You must configure the webpack to create the output in your desired format. You should not edit the build output.'

Comment: That's what I'm asking, how to configure the package in the format I need. I need the runtime.js to know that the files are in a folder '/ js'